# Employee/Company system improved

Tags: python

The following code tries to emulates a real employee/company relationship. I would like to recieve feedback on:

1. Any bad coding practices or code smells
2. Design in terms of practicality, effeciency, and ability to expand upon code

```py
class Company():
    def __init__(self, name, minimum_hiring_grades, required_work_experience_years,employee_leaves, employee_bonus_percent, employee_working_days) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.minimum_hiring_grades = minimum_hiring_grades
        self.required_work_experience_years =  required_work_experience_years
        self.employee_leaves = employee_leaves
        self.employee_bonus_percent = employee_bonus_percent
        self.employee_working_days = employee_working_days
        self.employee_base = []
        self.employees = []

    def hire_employee(self, employee) -> None:
        if employee.grades_percent_average >= self.minimum_hiring_grades and employee.work_experience_years >= self.required_work_experience_years:
            print("You are hired!")
            self.employee_base.append(employee)
            employee.has_job = True
            employee.working_days = self.employee_working_days
            employee.bonus_percent = self.employee_bonus_percent
            employee.available_leaves = self.employee_leaves
            employee.salary_dollars = employee.grades_percent_average + employee.work_experience_years * 1000
            employee.id = employee
        else:
            print("You did not meet our requirements.")

    def give_leaves_employee(self, employee, leaves_required) -> None:
        if leaves_required <= 3 and employee.available_leaves - leaves_required >= 0:
            employee.available_leaves -=  leaves_required
            print("Leaves are granted.")
        else:
            print("Leaves can't be granted.")

    def print_self_employees(self):
        self.employees = [employee.name for employee in self.employee_base]  
        print(self.employees)

    def fire_employee(self, employee):
        self.employee_del_attr(employee)
        print(f"{employee.name} is fired from {self.name}")

    def accept_employee_resignation(self, employee):
        self.employee_del_attr(employee)

    def employee_del_attr(self, employee):
        self.employee_base.remove(employee)
        del employee.company
        del employee.salary_dollars
        del employee.id
        employee.has_job = False

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, grades, work_experience_years):
        self.name = name
        self.grades_percent_average = grades
        self.work_experience_years = work_experience_years
        self.company = None
        self.working_days = None
        self.bonus_percent = None
        self.has_job = False
        self.id = None


    def apply_in_company(self, company):
        company.hire_employee(self)

    def ask_for_leaves(self, leaves_required):
        if self.has_job:
            self.company.give_leaves_employee(self, leaves_required)
        else:
            print("You do not have a job!")

    def resign_company(self, company) -> None:
        self.company.accept_employee_resignation(self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say much since the code isn't trying to solve anything yet.

`Employee` should be responsible for changing its own fields, `Company` doesn't need to know anything about it.

```
def hire_employee(self, employee) -> None:
   if employee.grades_percent_average >= self.minimum_hiring_grades and employee.work_experience_years >= self.required_work_experience_years:
        print("You are hired!")
        self.employee_base.append(employee)
        employee.has_job = True
        employee.working_days = self.employee_working_days
        employee.bonus_percent = self.employee_bonus_percent
        employee.available_leaves = self.employee_leaves
        employee.salary_dollars = employee.grades_percent_average + employee.work_experience_years * 1000
        employee.id = employee
    else:
        print("You did not meet our requirements.")
```

can be turned into

```
# Company
def try_hire_employee(self, employee) -> None:
    if (employee.grades_percent_average < self.minimum_hiring_grades or 
            employee.work_experience_years < self.required_work_experience_years):
        print("You did not meet our requirements.")
        return
    print("You are hired!")
    self.employee_base.append(employee)
    employee.accept_offer(self)

...

# Employee
def accept_offer(self, company):
    self.has_job = True
    self.working_days = company.employee_working_days
    self.bonus_percent = company.employee_bonus_percent
    self.available_leaves = company.employee_leaves
    self.salary_dollars = company.get_salary()
```

Same applies to `employee_del_attr()`.

Field name `id` shadows built-in `id()` method and is not used anywhere.

Functions such as `print_self_employees()` that just print stuff are meant to be [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). You don't want to change anything just by looking at it, <strike>it's not quantum physics</strike>. Then again, `self.employees` is never used so there is no reason to update it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on it, do you think there needs to be a Hirer composition model, where Hirer is a separate class which is initialised by the company and had access to the company's emplooye_base

Comment: @Illusioner_ I don't know, cause I don't know what this model is meant to solve. You need to think of some functionality first and then build models to implement it.

Comment: This is for my learning and understanding of OOP systems, in general, I'm trying to learn and implement good features that also might be a part of a real company system. An example of a feature I am trying to add is a way to promote employees.

Comment: @Illusioner_ I'd recommend adding some functionality that lets you interact with your system. Like managing a company from the command line. It will help you see whether design choices you made were good or you need something else.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that, I actually don't know anything about command line execution, but I will see how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

### `del` vs `= None`

```
def employee_del_attr(self, employee):
    self.employee_base.remove(employee)
    del employee.company
    del employee.salary_dollars
    del employee.id
    employee.has_job = False
```

Usage of `del` here catches my eye. I think `del` is often misunderstood or unnecessarily used as an over-optimization. Why not just set values to `None` instead of removing the attribute? What's not great about using `del` here is that it deletes the attributes off the object entirely such that attempting just to *read* some `employee.company` raises an `AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'company'`.

For example, I could imagine having some

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"Employee(id={self.id}) - {self.name}"
```

which looks innocent enough but after some call to `employee_del_attr`, now just `print(employee)` will break loudly.

Also agreed with @QuasiStellar that it's weird for the company to be doing all of this to the employee - it's not only mutating the employee, it's completely removing limbs!

### Use Guard Clauses to reduce indentation

[Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses) are a great way to reduce complexity when using `if` conditionals because instead of creating large diverging forks of code (if A then do Y else do Z), you change the logic to sequentially and explicitly handle the edge cases up front and then the happy path can remain as-is.

With `Company.hire_employee`, `Company.give_leaves_employee`, and `Employee.ask_for_leaves`, this would mean refactors like:

```py
def hire_employee(self, employee) -> None:
    employee_is_ineligible = employee.grades_percent_average < self.minimum_hiring_grades and employee.work_experience_years < self.required_work_experience_years
    if employee_is_ineligible:
        print("You did not meet our requirements.")
        return  # or maybe raise SomeError("You did not meet our requirements") instead of the print & return

    print("You are hired!")
    self.employee_base.append(employee)
    employee.has_job = True
    employee.working_days = self.employee_working_days
    employee.bonus_percent = self.employee_bonus_percent
    employee.available_leaves = self.employee_leaves
    employee.salary_dollars = employee.grades_percent_average + employee.work_experience_years * 1000
    employee.id = employee
```

### Use [named conditional expressions](https://refactoring.guru/consolidate-conditional-expression)

Also did you notice in the previous code, the contents of the `if` were moved into a variable for readability and maintainability. This could also be a separate method which better supports growing eligibility requirements and testability.

This same pattern could be applied to `give_leaves_employee`

### Typing annotations

It's curious to me that you have a few function return values annotated to `-> None` but not much else *and* it's inconsistent. Typing was designed to be progressive so any (correct) typings are better than none, but even still something that may seem redundant like

```py
def hire_employee(self, employee: Employee) -> None:
    ...
```

provides benefits for both the consumer *and* author of such a function because static type checkers and IDEs can help flag and inform what that variable is expected to be and you can get intellisense while writing within the function itself.

Comment: Hey, thanks this was really helpful, I was going to add the typing annotations, but didn't think about using ```None```. Any Idea on how I can separate responsibilities to the employee?

Comment: wrt separating responsibilities b/w Company & Employee, I think @QuasiStellar's suggestions of having the Employee handle its own internals through public interfaces that the Company leverages is the best start/feedback. For example if a company fires an employee, the company probably handles removing them from their employee base and then the employee can have its own method the company calls which does more employee-specific stuff.

Comment: Beyond that it's a little tough to say. I'd generally say design your thing and then put it to the test to start figuring out where abstractions start to feel leaky or wrong and then refactor from there rather than get too stuck upfront. Like 1 Q that I have going back to evaluate is "Does it make sense for an Employee entity to exist after they've been fired from a Company?" Like how much total ownership does a Company object have over corresponding Employee objects? Can one exist without the other? For example: Company.fire_employee which removes them lists and then employee.deactivate()

Comment: An employee here is basically a graduate who if fired, can apply in another company, thanks for your suggestions though

Comment: I think that'd be a good case for Company.fire_employee to remove them from the company's systems(lists) and then just `Employee.leave_company()` then!

Comment: Oh ok, that' a great idea! What I did after your feedback was then company calling a method I created called ```employee.self_delete_attr()```, which is also used in the resignation function now.